# Category and its Core classes

Tags: ios, categories

If I create a category on one of the core classes in IOS, Eg UIImage, then will i have to always import the header where in I have declared its interface, or because UIImage being part of UIKit, will automatically include the new formed category wherever there is a UIKIT import??

Another thing. What if i create a category and not decide to use its functions altogether in some classes? Will those be still accesible?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1

Comment: Follow this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-categories--mobile-10648). May be this link provide you some help to understand the Category use in ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the category into a class (Generally the .m file) where you use one of the methods in that category

There is no need to import the category if you're not using any of those category methods in a class.